# How to enable the publish option for Configured modules?

Tags: magnolia

The publish option is disabled by default for the modules presented in Configuration App. How can we enable publish for these items.
[image]

Thanks,
Vijay Kodali

Answer (score 0):

Publishing is disabled there for a reason. Configuration of modules is often different between author and public instances. You should not be attempting to enable this, but rather selectively publish only changes at lower levels that you made, and that you know for sure need to go to public instance.

HTH,
Jan